# Python　辞書での組み合わせと重複について

Tags: python

値の左から順に同じグループになります。
例えば、group1では、Aのaの1が一つのグループで、また別に、Aのaの2、Bのaの2、Cのbの1、Dのaの1、Dのaの3、Dのbの3となり、7つのグループが存在することになります。

```
dict1 = {"group1":["A","A","B","D","C","D","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","N","K","L","K","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","a","b","b","a","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","2","3","1","1","3"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","1","2","2","2","2"]}
```

以下がdict1,dict2,dict3という辞書に対して行いたい処理です。

それぞれのgroupの中で値を照合
アルファベットの小文字を基に数値を比べ、同じ大文字がどれくらいあるか判別（group１の中では、aの1はA,Dがあり、aの2ではAがあるので、同じ大文字のAを抜き出す。
また、aの1はA,Dがあり、aの3ではDがあるので、同じ大文字のDを抜き出す。しかし、aの1はA,Dがあり、bの3ではDがあるが、aとbが違うので比較しない。）し、
それぞれのグループごとにアルファベットの大文字を書き出す。
結果を立て並びに出力する
以下のように出力したいです。

```
result =

group1
a  1 , a  2   A  #dict2,dict3,dict1の情報を示します
a  1 , a  3   D
a  2 , a  3
b  1 , b  3 

group2
a  1 , a  2   
a  1 , a  3   
a  1 , a  4   
a  2 , a  3   
a  2 , a  4   
a  3 , a  4   

group3
a  1 , a  2   K
```

知識不足ながらプログラム案を考えてみましたが、組み合わせをして、共通のものを取り出すことができません。ご教示お願い致します。

```
from itertools import groupby


keyfunc = lambda x: x[:2]
result_ctype = [(g, {k: [i[-1] for i in v]
           for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(dict3[g], dict2[g], dict1[g]), key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)})
      for g in dict1.keys()]

#出力
[('group1', {('a', '1'): ['A', 'D'], ('a', '2'): ['A', 'B'], ('a', '3'): ['D'], ('b', '1'): ['C'], ('b', '3'): ['D']}), ('group2', {('a', '1'): ['E', 'F'], ('a', '2'): ['G'], ('a', '3'): ['H'], ('a', '4'): ['I']}), ('group3', {('a', '1'): ['J', 'N', 'K'], ('a', '2'): ['L', 'K'], ('b', '2'): ['M', 'N']})]
```

Comment: 要件の説明が足りないですよ。出力例を元に推測させるのではなく、質問内の文章で明確に定義しましょう。具体的にはソート、重複排除、組み合わせの要件が抜けています。出力例は必要なデータをどう表示するかでしかなく、そのデータ定義は文章で明快にしないといけないということです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from itertools import groupby, combinations

dict1 = {"group1":["A","A","B","D","C","D","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","N","K","L","K","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","a","b","b","a","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","2","3","1","1","3"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","1","2","2","2","2"]}

kf = lambda x: x[:2]
for g in dict1.keys():
    d = {k: [i[-1] for i in v]
         for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(dict2[g], dict3[g], dict1[g]), key=kf), key=kf)}
    print(g)
    for _, i in groupby(d.keys(), key=lambda k: k[0]):
        for a, b in combinations(i, 2):
            print(*a, ',', *b, *(set(d[a]) & set(d[b])))

# group1
# a 1 , a 2 A
# a 1 , a 3 D
# a 2 , a 3
# b 1 , b 3
# group2
# a 1 , a 2
# a 1 , a 3
# a 1 , a 4
# a 2 , a 3
# a 2 , a 4
# a 3 , a 4
# group3
# a 1 , a 2 K
```